# What is said at the end of "I Dream Myself Alive", and why?

Tags: lyrics, meaning, pop, sample

At the very end of the a-ha song "I Dream Myself Alive" (2:56 to 2:59), there's a barely audible voice in German. I believe it says "Die Berichterstattung soll umfassend, wahrheitsge-" ("The reporting should be comprehensive, truthf-"), which is the (truncated) beginning of a provision in various German laws and treaties on public broadcasting (e.g. [§ 6 of the ZDF-Staatsvertrag](https://bravors.brandenburg.de/de/vertraege-213727#6)).

I couldn't find anything about this sample anywhere.

- Do you agree that's what it says?
- Any idea why they might have chosen this text? I can't discern any connection to the lyrics.